# Untrained Network Giving 80% Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have a two class classification problem and my neural network prior to training predicts with an accuracy of 80%. After training i have an accuracy of 75%. Can you tell me how this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your class imbalance is roughly 4:1, then a network that always predicts the more frequent class would have an accuracy of 80%. (That's why accuracy alone is an insufficient metric: for binary classification, you should use ROC and PRC curves. There are also more holistic scalar metrics such as MCC)

Let's say your positive samples are the frequent class. Without training, a random network might always output positive (80% accuracy). In this case, you'd only have true positives and false positives. After training, the network might start to also predict negatives; then you'll start getting true and false positives in addition to true and false negatives, which could yield a lower accuracy.

Comment: Accuracy is an insufficient metric when the classes are balanced, too! https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274

Comment: Agreed. ROC and PRC curves are standard for binary classification and probably best for avoiding arbitrary thresholding

Comment: I do not think I fully agree with the answer above. Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't the model naturally converge towards favoring the more frequent class given it is optimised with loss? That means it should learn to just predict the positive class. If so I would not expect it to have a less good accuracy.


Should the above be correct, one cannot rule out the possibility of problems with training methodology/bug.

Comment: There are a couple assumptions going on here. 1. We don't know if the model converged. We only know the accuracy before and after training. 2. We don't know their loss function/methods. There are a lot of ways training can decrease accuracy from a random initialization. If your optimizer is maximizing a metric other than accuracy, then accuracy could absolutely decrease in favor of, for example, F1 or MCC. Class penalties are also commonly applied to loss functions to virtually balance the classes. However the OP trained, it's likely there's a 4:1 imbalance given the accuracy on initialization

Comment: Great points. 1/ no convergence in the model should denote potential issues in training methodology or the signal in the data. 2/ NN optimizers can only focus on minimizing loss and so i believe you refer to model scoring? I did assume OP used acc for that matter given his question.

Generally, my only point is that the response above makes it look like worse than random is natural or expected wheras I argue that one should find a good reason for that to happen (no signal in the data, training methodology etc). Thanks for excellent discussion.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your model does worse than a random guess for a number of reasons. Some of those could be

- **noisy data**: your model focuses to noise  in the dataset rather than features that have predictive value. May be worth inspecting your dataset and look for relevant issues and class imbalance
- **early stopping/best model**: Would be worth to have a look at learning curves and make sure that you are storing the weights of the model that performed best during training.
- **no value in the dataset**: a model will produce predictions that may not necessarily be correlated to the labels especially in the case where there is nothing really to learn.